# How to loop through multiple result sets from stored procedure in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

Im slightly going out of my mind trying to get 3 result sets from a stored procedure (SP) in SQL server 2008.

*[Stored procedure](http://pastebin.com/dnds3KGn)*:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE db_abbTest
AS
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT 1
        SELECT 2
        SELECT 3
        RETURN 0
END
GO
```

[*PHP code*](http://pastebin.com/PCHyQCJA):

```
<?php

$serverName = "server";
$connectionInfo = array("UID"=> "user", "PWD" =>"pass", "Database"=>"sample_db");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn )
{
    $sql = "db_AbbTest";
    $r = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, null, array(
            'Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC,
            'SendStreamParamsAtExec'    => true
        ));
    var_dump($r);
        while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch( $r))
        {
              var_dump($obj);
              var_dump(sqlsrv_fetch_array($r));
        }
     echo "Connection established.\n";
}
else
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Close the connection. */
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

The SP returns three results (3x select statements) however i cannot seem to get all of the results back from the query. Any Ideas?
I have tried `while(sqlsrv_fetch_object($r){//do something})`
but no luck..

Comment: What result *do* you get?  That is, what are the results of `var_dump`?

Comment: @Siva, thought pastebin was an accepted solution for fairly big code sections? Wallyk i get true for `var_dump($obj)` and blank for the second..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this issue, I had to use a while loop and then move to the next result:

```
$sql = "{call db_AbbTest}";
$r = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, null);
$i =0;
    while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($r))
    {
            echo $i;
         print_r($obj);
         sqlsrv_next_result($r);
         $i++;
    }
```