# Can't retrieve data from stored procedure that has insert or other than select query inside of it even though the final result is still select

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a single stored procedure that has update and select statement inside of it. I want to retrieve the data from the stored procedure from PHP but always returning an empty rows.

When I execute the procedure from SQL Server directly, it works just fine. It update specific column first, and then shows the updated column using a select statement.

But when I want to retrieve data from the procedure with PHP using `sql_srv`, it just returns an empty row which resulting an error in for each argument.

Here is the stored procedure I use :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[xsp_test3] 
    @xxUID AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @xxToken AS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbuser 
    SET lastlogin = GETDATE(), 
        LatestDeviceToken = @xxToken 
    WHERE UID = @xxUID;

    SELECT @xxUID AS UID;
END
```

And here is the PHP code I use to retrieve the data :

```
$tsql = "exec xsp_test3 'motvl4g3SsXfeF84RK4D1E0yDP92',''"; 
$resultx = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql); 

while($recentBadge = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultx, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = $recentBadge;
} 

foreach($result as $recentBadge) {
    print_r($recentBadge); 
}
```

It always returning an empty rows hence resulting error :

> Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\digitalmember\ios\login2.php on line 38
>   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\digitalmember\ios\login2.php on line 38

BUT, when I comment the update statement inside of the stored procedure, IT WORKS FINE. Why is that happening? Is there any workaround for this? It will be pointless if I remove the update statement since that is the most important for this to work.

Comment: If `@xxUID` is an input parameter, why do you need to return it (via a `SELECT` or `OUTPUT` parameter)? The value of `@xxUID` isn't changed in the SP, but PHP is already aware of the value of `@xxUID`, as it defined it's value.

Comment: @Larnu thats just example, the real one is not just that, but point is whenever the update statement exist , i can't retrieve the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SET NOCOUNT ON`, e.g.:

```sql
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[xsp_test3] 
    @xxUID as varchar(max),
    @xxToken  as varchar(max)
As
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update tbuser
    set lastlogin = GETDATE(), LatestDeviceToken = @xxToken
    where UID = @xxUID;

    select @xxUID as UID;
END
```

PHP is probably getting confused when it sees rowcount 1 (update) followed by another rowcount 1 (select).

Comment: Adding that without `SET NOCOUNT ON`, the app code will need to [consume multiple results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419642/how-to-loop-through-multiple-result-sets-from-stored-procedure-in-php) in order to process the `DONE_IN_PROC` (row count message) preceding the desired result set.

Comment: WORKS LIKE MAGIC, thanks. been searching for this in with many kind of search keys combination in stack overflow but all the question just select only withouth insert or update statement. so i just make the new one